# How to use data-target in url

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Pls, how can I use data-target as URL like for example in login.php, data-target = "#sign-up" and I want to add the sign-up in the URL like header('Locations: login.php#sign-up');

I tried it but its not working

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use data-target for that, you'd just use a normal link with the id in the `href`.

For example:

```
<a href="#sign-up">Click Me</a>
```

Would add `#sign-up` to the end of the URL and jump the page to the element with the id of `sign-up`.